# Is it possible to use Haxe parameterized types in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, generics, haxe

Is there any way I can use a parameterized Haxe type like this:

```
class GenericTest<T> {

   public function putSomething(value:T) {
      ...
   }

   public function getSomething():T {
      ...
   }

}
```

in ActionScript?

```
var o:GenericTest.<int> = new GenericTest.<int>();
```

I tried building to a `.swc` and including that but the type parameters turn to plain Objects. It seems like there must be a way to trick flash into using custom generic types if the support exists for `Vector`. Or is that a special case built into the player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, it looks impossible without compiler modifications according to these two posts:

- http://www.davidarno.org/2011/04/19/as3-user-defined-generics-why-they-are-not-possible-yet/
- http://alecmce.com/as3/why-we-need-generics-in-as3

That's disappointing but I can't say I didn't expect it.